# Fire query on ajax post url page

Tags: wp-query, ajax, wpdb

Here i am sending the ajax response to load_post.php page from my ajax call.I am getting response on load_post.php on load_post.php i have to fire word press query.

I was try this but getting bellow error in response.when i add global $wpdb variable into load_post.php file

```
Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_GLOBAL in <b>/home/skovianc/public_html/test/thefoodieclub.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-booking/load_post.php
```

ajax code

```
var time=0;
jQuery("#time_slot").change(function()
                                {   
                                time=time_slot.value;
                            $.post("'. plugins_url().'/woocommerce-booking/load_post.php",
                                 {name: time},
                                  function(response){
                                  console.log(response);
                                  }
                                );  
                                 });
```

post url file load_post.php code here i want fire wpdb query

```
<?php session_start();
    echo $name= $_POST["name"];
    file_put_contents("name.txt", $name)
```

//Query will be some thing like

```
global $wpdb;
echo $query = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT start_date FROM {$wpdb->prefix}booking_history");


 ?>
```

So how can fire query on ajax post url page load_post.php

Comment: Your error is because you execute `load_post.php` expecting Wordpress engine be loaded in that but it is obviously not. Please, refer to [Wordpress Ajax API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) any of the several questions about [how to use Ajax in Wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=how+to+use+Ajax+in+Wordpress).

Comment: is there any way with this what i am looking for